# Using code point to render outlined icon instead of filled from Material Design Google Fonts

Tags: html, css, material-design, google-fonts, codepoint

I have a Place icon from [Material Icons Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons%20Outlined:place:&icon.query=location&icon.style=Outlined&icon.set=Material%20Icons&icon.platform=web) that is rendered using a `before` pseudo-selector and the code point `e55f`.

The problem is that is being rendered the filled version:
[image: Material Design location filled icon]

Instead of the outlined version I want:
[image: Material Design location outlined icon]

Is there a way I can use the outlined version using code point?

[Demo from Codepen here](https://codepen.io/ricardo-castaneda/pen/LYMYYje)

```
<link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" as="style">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" as="style" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />

<div class="place"></div>

<style>
  .place::before {
    content: "\e55f";
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the `font-family: 'Material Symbols Outlined';` :

```css
.place::before {
  content: "\e55f";
  font-family: 'Material Symbols Outlined';
}
```

```html
<link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" as="style">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" as="style" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />

<div class="place"></div>
```